# Track all files in a directory to git LFS but ignore a single folder present in that directory

Tags: git, git-lfs

Say I have a directory "my_dir" and some files in it. And I have a subdirectory in it "my_dir_subdir".

File structure:
"my_dir/my_dir_subdir".

How to track my_dir via git LFS but not track "my_dir/my_dir_subdir/" via git LFS

Answer (score 10):

Seems like you can disable a certain rule with preceding it with a hyphen:

```
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
Dependencies/*.png -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
```