# How to make git LFS not apply to a subdirectory

Tags: git, git-lfs, gitattributes

My repository uses git LFS and includes lines such as this one in its .gitattributes:

```
*.jar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

There's one .jar file that I want to store in the repo directly, not involving LFS. Ideally, I would make LFS not apply to anything under the directory that contains that jar. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is [largely sourced from this github comment](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2120#issuecomment-290754993)

The syntax for `.gitattributes` allows you to "minus" an attribute -- removing it from already being included (see: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-Unset)

This allows you un-lfs a file that was previously included (the example from the github thread):

```
*.asset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
Assets/Resources/*.asset -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
```

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to this just worked for us.

```
*.asset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
TheAssetIWantToExclude.asset !filter !diff !merge -text
```

This was for `git version 2.17.1.windows.2` today.  Comments further in Anthony Sottile's github link provided this answer.

For the existing file we used

```
git rm --cached TheAssetIWantToExclude.asset
git add TheAssetIWantToExclude.asset
git commit
```

to get the file copied to the repo.

Comment: This worked for me with `2.17.1` on Ubuntu, while the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: [Track all files in a directory to git LFS but ignore a single folder present in that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428178/track-all-files-in-a-directory-to-git-lfs-but-ignore-a-single-folder-present-in)

TL;DR, it's not possible unless you move the folder, or use `git lfs track` for each individual subdir.

Comment: Please see my answer for an example that just worked for us on `git version 2.17.1.windows.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), I think that the correct syntax is actually:

```
*.asset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
Assets/Resources/*.asset -filter -diff -merge -text
```

Specifically, this part:

> **Unset**
> <...> this is specified by listing the name of the attribute prefixed with a dash `-` in the attribute list.

*(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Unset)*

---

More than that, you can define a macro attribute (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_macro_attributes) to simplify your `.gitattributes` file and to make the intent clearer:

```
[attr]not-lfs -filter -diff -merge -text

*.asset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
Assets/Resources/*.asset not-lfs
```